# Automatic addition of the day of the week for CharField in models.py

Tags: django, django-models

I have a very simple model to choose days of the week in my language, it looks like this:

```
class Day(models.Model):
DAY_OF_WEEK = (
    ('Monday', 'Poniedziałek'),
    ('Tuesday', 'Wtorek'),
    ('Wednesday', 'Środa'),
    ('Thursday', 'Czwartek'),
    ('Friday', 'Piątek'),
    ('Saturday', 'Sobota'),
    ('Saturday', 'Niedziela')
)
    day_week = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=DAY_OF_WEEK, default=date.today)
```

How can I set the field automatically in my form to be set to the current day of the week? adding this to my model does not work according to my expectations (`default=date.today`). Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Define a function in order to get the default value for `week_day`

```
def get_default():
    week_day = date.today().weekday()
    if week_day == 0:
        return "Monday"
    if week_day == 1:
        return "Tuesday"
    if week_day == 2:
        return "Wednesday"
    if week_day == 3:
        return "Thursday"
    if week_day == 4:
        return "Friday"
    if week_day == 5:
        return "Saturday"
    if week_day == 6:
        return "Sunday"



class Day(models.Model):
#####################
# model fields....
#####################

    week_day = models.CharField(max_length=15, default=get_default)
```